# Hpw to replace a specific text inside pipe delimited text in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a text inside a cell like this:

```
12|27|87|67
```

it's a list of `Id` separated with the pipe symbol.

I want to replace a specific text (`Hi there`) instead of these numbers, I want it to look like this:

```
Hi there|Hi there|Hi there|Hi there
```

This `Hi there` text replaces those numbers along with pipe symbol.

How to do this in MS Excel?

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Excel does not include the `SEQUENCE()` function, then use:

```
=MID(REPT("|Hi there",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",""))+1),2,99)
```

[image]

Comment: Even if you have sequence, this is shorter.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Still your answer has definite tutorial value.

Answer (score 0):

If one has the Dyamic Array formula SEQUENCE():

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,INDEX({"Hi There"},SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",""))+1)^0))
```

[image]